# How can I view which apps I've purchased?

Tags: store

I can't recall all the apps and games I purchased before I had to do a reset of my phone. Is there any way to see my order history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view your purchase history on the Windows Phone website.

Direct link: https://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/my/purchase-history

Answer (score 2):

This page shows all account transactions, as well as the price paid and payment method:
https://commerce.microsoft.com/PaymentHub/Transaction